# How to wait message like mqwi_unlimited in c++

Tags: c++, ibm-mq

I'm new with WebsphereMQ C++. I would like to ask how to wait indefinitely for the incoming message, without using **WaitInterval (MQWI_UNLIMITED)** because when I am using this mqwi_unlimited it then waits for the message for a long time as expected but the application is like "hanging" when going into a loop of getting messages ***(queue.get( msg, gmo ))***.

I am thinking of setting wait interval into some seconds then reconnect or something like that. Is it possible?

How can I wait for a message without getting an error of **"NO AVAILABLE MESSAGE (MQRC 2033)?"**

The reason I ask this question is I am creating a daemon which waits for a message then do some process. The application is "stack" only on getting the message, I tried to replace the (MQWI_UNLIMITED) and it proceeds to the next process..

//====DAEMON===//

rcv->start(); -this is the get (loop of getting message)

snd->start(); - this is the put

let's say the application start to get and process the message but after that it never execute the **snd->start()**

Please help me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to ask how to wait indefinitely for the incoming message,
>   without using WaitInterval (MQWI_UNLIMITED)

That **IS** how you wait indefinitely.

You can use the call-back method for getting a message, go look up MQCB API call.